# Creating two package image from single bitbake recipe script, (way to define two MACHINE variable in local.conf file)

Tags: openembedded

How to create two package image from single bitbake recipie script. 
These package are created from same source and it should only differs in some of the patch.

> >
>   or

How to build openembedded simultaneously for two machine, any way to define multiple MACHINE variable in local.conf file, so that while build it build and creates images for two different machine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to assign multiple values to the MACHINE variable. You could run BitBake several times with different values for MACHINE though.

One way to do this would be not to set MACHINE in local.conf but to set it externally and pass it to BitBake as an environment variable.

```
MACHINE="machine1"
export MACHINE

BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="MACHINE"
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE

./bitbake helloworld-image
```

This way, you would get images for each machine in separate directories under tmp/deploy/images .

You could then automate building for several machines with a shell script like this:

```
MACHINES="machine1 machine2 machine3"
for MACHINE in "$MACHINES" ; do
    ...
done
```

You can find more information about BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE here:  http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Advanced_configuration#Whitelist_Environment_Variables

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is the what i actually needed